# strip TypeScript annotations without other transpilation (including Stage 3 proposals) and retaining line breaks

Tags: typescript, babeljs

How can I strip out all TS types and type annotations from a TS 3.9 module without performing any other transpilation (including private class fields like `#foo`) and while retaining line breaks in my original code?

I'm contributing to an OSS project that uses plain JS with Stage 3 proposals, but I'd like to build my code in TypeScript and use an automated build step to strip out all TS annotations and end up with an .mjs file that I can check in upstream.

My code doesn't use any TS features (e.g. namespaces, enums) that have a runtime footprint. I'm just using TS for type checking.

So far I've tried both TSC and Babel, but each of them have problems.

Here's the TSC version:

```sh
tsc src/lib/LocalDateTime.ts --lib ESNext --target ESNext --module ESNext --isolatedModules --declaration --allowSyntheticDefaultImports --moduleResolution node --useDefineForClassFields true
mv code.js code.mjs
```

TSC leaves all my code alone, but it [doesn't preserve newlines](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/843). Without line spacing between blocks of code, the resulting code is much harder to read and isn't suitable for being checked in upstream.

TSC also messes up indenting, but prettier can fix that. It's only the line breaks that I need to retain. I'm not interested in post-TSC formatters which attempt to add line breaks in an automated way. I just want to keep the original line breaks in my original code.

Here's a Babel 7.10 config that is also close to working:

```
{
  "retainLines": true,
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      {
        "allowNamespaces": false,
        "onlyRemoveTypeImports": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

That config leaves my line breaks alone (good!) but it also transpiles use of [Stage 3 private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) which is bad because I want to keep native `#foo` property syntax in the JS output. I just want my runtime code left alone but the TS parts stripped out.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that developing in this manner will come back to bite you, and quickly, but you can configure babel to parse, but not to transform, most syntax. By using an parallel set of plugins,

In this case, change `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` becomes `@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties`

**.babelrc.json**

```
{
  "retainLines": true,
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      {
        "allowNamespaces": false,
        "onlyRemoveTypeImports": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here's an example in the [repl](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQMQDMD22Bc0EALgE4CWAdgOYDcSAvkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.2&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-syntax-class-properties%407.10.1%2C%40babel%2Fplugin-transform-typescript%407.10.1).

Comment: perfect, thanks. re: "developing in this manner will come back to bite you", usually this would be a bad idea but in this case it's not clear if the code will end up in the OSS library (in which case it will get merged as .mjs and future development will be in JS only) or whether it will be a separate TS library built on top of that JS library. Until the decision is made one way or the other (within a month or two) I wanted a way to make updates to both TS and JS without risking getting them out of sync. So it's just a short-term thing, not a long-term plan which I agree would be bad!